# What is causing sharp creases on subdivided model?

Tags: modeling

I am doing [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WVr4fPFUr2E) Blenderguru tutorial to work on my modelling skills. In the image below I have marked some areas where I made some modelling mistakes. Now I would like to learn what I have done wrong and how best to repair those mistakes.

[image]

Here you can see some details of the top left corner:

[image]

**Area 1** What made that sharp crease in area 1 ? And how to remove that ?

**Area 2** Why this "sharp" shape in area 2 ? And how to remove that ?

[image]

**Area 3** The glass of the iphone and the metal ring don't abut against each other. There is a "gap" between those two objects. How can I repair that ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The sharp crease there is caused by a set of duplicate vertices. To fix it you just need to select all the vertices (<kbd>A</kbd>) and Remove Doubles (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>, Remove Doubles).
2. Those sharp edges are occurring because of your edge split modifier. Remove it to get a smoother look. I also recommend adding in another support loop on the right side of the gap in order to get better smoothing, like so.

[image: another loop]

3. To solve this you need to add more loops towards the bottom (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>), and move all of the loops at the bottom up a little bit. I recommend putting loops next to the points on the main phone where it transitions from the curves of the corner to the straightaway. After you've added the loops, select them one at a time and move them up along the Z axis so that the limit surface of the subdivision surface modifier just touches the bottom of the phone. You can use the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key during the grab to move the points more slowly and position them more precisely. Here's the result I get from doing that:

[image: more geometry is needed to get a good result]

In addition you should probably set the screen part of the phone to be shaded smooth before you put together the final render. In Edit mode, select everything and then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>, Shade Smooth to get the smooth shading you probably want to have for the final render.

Comment: hi thanks a lot. I can now solve the first two issues. but I cannot manage to solve the third one. I added an image to show what I mean ... the circled line is not a loop cut is it ? I don't reality get your instructions on the third issue

Comment: You'll probably need another support loop on the left and right sides of the frame... If I were you I'd also add some more geometry on the main screen of the phone in order to capture the curvature of the corners better. The series of edges you circled is not an edge loop because it has two points with five edges going from them. Vertices that don't have 2 or 4 edges coming out of them are called poles, and they terminate edge loops.

Comment: As far as my instructions go, I took the approach of adding more edge loops on the frame of the phone rather than on the screen and moving those loops into place.